# Nesting Excel Logic Tests

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I'm having issues nestling logic tests in Excel.  I'm trying to get a cell to return a value based on whether it meets an "AND" or "OR" or neither.

**Something like:**

```
If Value A = "True" and Value B = "True" and Value C = "True" then "Return Value"

else
If Value A = "True" or Value B = "True" or Value C = "True" then "Return Value"

else 
"Return Value"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use AND() and OR() function within your if statements. For example:

`=IF(AND(Value A,Value B,Value C), Return Value(IF), IF(OR(Value A,Value B,Value C), Return Value (ElseIF), Return Value (Else)))`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I needed.